# Java 6 SNI (Server Name Indication)?

Tags: java, ssl, https, bouncycastle, sni

Is it possible to use TLS + SNI with java 6?

TLS works nicely with java 6, but SNI doesn't seem to be supported.

With java 7 and higher it works fine. But i'm stuck on java 6.

Java 6 advanced has SNI support but it does cost over 10k, which i currently do not have...

I also took a look at bouncy castle which has a one reference to SNI rfc 6066 in URLAndHash. But a simple test with TlsClientProtocol and DefaultTlsClient doesn't seem to result in SNI working. The docs are very sparse to non existing though on the subject.

Are there more things i can try?

Answer (score 0):

You can update to a later version of Java.

The latest publicly-available version of [Java 6 is Java SE 6 Update 45, which was made available on April 16, 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_6_updates).

There are probably well [over 300 listed unfixed vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php?vendor_id=93&product_id=19117&version_id=&page=1&hasexp=0&opdos=0&opec=0&opov=0&opcsrf=0&opgpriv=0&opsqli=0&opxss=0&opdirt=0&opmemc=0&ophttprs=0&opbyp=0&opfileinc=0&opginf=0&cvssscoremin=0&cvssscoremax=0&year=0&month=0&cweid=0&order=1&trc=475&sha=e7bd4bdaede94939bbb984bced9c264b834fc20c) in that latest publicly-available version of Java 6.

Assuming this is for a commercial product, are you customers aware of that?

Comment: I'm already using the latest java 6, u45 is the last public one u131 is the one with SNI. Updating to 7 or 8 is no option. Customers are to blame...